# selecting checkboxes in a div using jquery is not working in chrome but working in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have few `checkboxes` inside a `div`. All these `checkboxes` are placed under a `label` for formatting issues. I have a list which contains names of checkboxes & these checboxes must get checked on some action. Here is the list: `var columns= ['2','5','4']`

This is how the HTML looks:

```
 <div id="menu" class="dropdown-menu hold-on-click dropdown-checkboxes pull-right">
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '1'>1</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '2'>2</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '3'>3</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '4'>4</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '5'>5</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '6'>6</label>
</div>
```

**The below code is working in IE and firefox but not in chrome. Please suggest different code or let me know if I can fix the bug in this code.**

```
$('input', $('#menu')).each(function () {
                var chkBoxName = $(this).attr('name');
                 var selected = columns.indexOf(chkBoxName);
                 if(selected !== -1){
                  $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
                  console.log(chkBoxName +  $(this).attr('checked'));
              }
            });
```

I saw this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Znu/) it runs fine in IE but not in chrome. I think I am running into same issue. The reason is second checkbox is under table in this case. I am not sure whats the issue in my case.

this is what happens in chrome 34

[image]

Comment: You have a problem with your input 2 :  name = "2'.

Comment: Now the question is: What happens in IE and FF, and what happens in Chrome instead? I.e. define "working" and "not working". Also, do you really have identical `id`s for every `input`?

Comment: `$(this).prop('checked', 'checked');` is not the correct usage either, it expects a boolean. It just so happens `"checked"` will evaluate to true. I would expect to see `$(this).prop('checked', true);` there

Comment: @Teemu: by problem I mean after the execution of this code, checkboxes with name `2,5,4` get checked in IE and fireforx but not in chrome.

Comment: Oddly, your code seems to [work in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/1nr1ae05/) too. The issue has to be outside of the snippet you've posted.

Comment: @Teemu: run this fiddle in IE and then in chrome. you will see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/n7Znu/

Comment: @SharpCoder I can't see any difference between Chrome and IE, when running my fiddle linked above. It works as well in FF. Your fiddle has some invalid HTML, if fixed, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/0t6tj9mh/) as well.

Comment: @Teemu: Thank you for quick response. I have attached the image from the fiddle. I am using chrome 34. Really confused now :(

Comment: @SharpCoder My previous comment might be a bit badly worded. I meant, that [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nr1ae05/) I've created on basis on the code in the post works in Chrome (37). [The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Znu/) you've linked in a comment above, is not working due to invalid HTML, which is fixed in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t6tj9mh/) I've linked in my previous comment. There is no standard for how browsers should handle invalid HTML, hence it might work in one browser, but not in another.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have problems with your HTML :

- All your chackebox have the same ID
- Your label must not contain the input

  ```
  <label for="cbox1">1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" data-column="1" name="1">
  ```

And your code works for me : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lw9k9zd4/

Comment: Nesting the `input` inside the label is [perfectly valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL).

Comment: Don't know that. My bad

Comment: @Arthur. Check the fiddle i have added.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="menu" class="dropdown-menu hold-on-click dropdown-checkboxes pull-right">
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '1'>1</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" data-column="0" name = '2'>2</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" data-column="0" name = '3'>3</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" data-column="0" name = '4'>4</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" data-column="0" name = '5'>5</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox5" data-column="0" name = '6'>6</label>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#menu input").each(function(index, element) {
             $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
        });

    });
```